# Setting responsive handlers in React then using them in scss

Tags: reactjs, sass

I have a custom Hook that detects whether the app is the mobile or desktop version. Serving up 2 versions of components works but I am at a loss on how to pass the variable to a scss file.

[The code sandbox demo is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-margulis-itk3t?file=/src/App.js:259-268).

In my app.js I have a couple of classes that are modified based on `@media (max-width: 768px)` within the scss file. This would be fine if I only had 1 style but with multiple styles, I would like to find a way to set in React which style to use.

How do I use `{windowSize}` to pass a JS variable to a .scss file? If I used styled-component what would it look like?

```
import "./app.scss";
import useWindowSize from "./useWindowSize";

export default function App() {
  const windowSize = useWindowSize();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Making the app responsive</h1>
      <h2 className="TestTitle">{windowSize}</h2>
      <p className="BoxWidth">Hello world</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Styling looks like this:

```
$width: 768px;
$Colour1: rgb(0, 255, 213);

.BoxWidth {
  background-color: green;
  @media (max-width: $width) {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

Comment: The short answer is you can't pass a JS variable to a .scss file. Is styled-components or other CSS-in-JS libraries an option?

Comment: Yes, styled-components looks like the only way I can see now. How would this look?

Comment: @Aron, if you want to post your comment as an answer I'm happy to award as it may help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it with [`styled-components`](https://styled-components.com/):

```
const Box = styled.div` // or 'p' depending on which element you want to use
  background-color: green;

  // Note that you are using a 'width' prop that needs to be passed in
  @media (max-width: ${({ width }) => width}) {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  const windowSize = useWindowSize();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      ...
      // You pass the window size in as the width prop
      <Box width={windowSize}>Hello world</Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

See [your modified codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-almeida-110sj?file=/src/App.js:44-83)

**EDIT**

We clarified the question in chat. To which this is the solution:

```
const commonStyles = { background: "pink", height: 100, margin: "0 auto" };
const SmallComponent = () => <div style={{ ...commonStyles, width: "100%" }} />;
const LargeComponent = () => (
  <div style={{ ...commonStyles, width: "500px" }} />
);

const Box = styled.div`
  color: white;
  background-color: ${({ isMobile }) => (isMobile ? "green" : "lightblue")};
`;

export default function App() {
  const windowSize = useWindowSize();

  const isMobile = windowSize === "useMobileVersion";

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Making the app responsive</h1>
      <h2>{windowSize}</h2>
      <Box isMobile={isMobile}>Hello world</Box>
      {isMobile ? <SmallComponent /> : <LargeComponent />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The original codesandbox link has been updated with this latest answer.

Comment: This makes sense though I just looked at the modified sandbox and I think there is a misunderstanding of "windowSize" as the values are text: either "useMobileVersion" or "useDesktopVersion". We can use number values instead tho I'd prefer not a boolean as I may expand to tablet in future projects.

Comment: Sure, I just went with the assumption they were numbers, but the concept is the same. Once you have information about the screen size in your component you can pass in a width prop. Whether `windowSize` is a number or a string that you use to set another variable doesn't matter. The logic is the same.

Comment: Are you able to help modify the sandbox? I'm relatively new to reactjs and understand the concept but am having trouble getting the required results.

Comment: Do you want help changing the hook? Or adapting my component code to use the hook return string?

Comment: Whichever you feel is best? I suppose changing the hook (at least to numeric) for sure and possibly the component.

Comment: I've made a change. Check it out. I hope it helps.

Comment: Hmmm, it doesn't change colour. It starts with blue and does not change to green regardless of width.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're trying to achieve? I'm not actually clear on what your goal is or why it can't be achieved with simple media queries.

Comment: For the codesandbox: If the window size is wider than 768px the colour should change from green to blue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227920/discussion-between-virtualbis-and-aron).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `if else`.

For example:

```
export default function App() {
  const windowSize = useWindowSize();
  const csTestTiele = windowSize <= 768 ? "TestTitleSmall" : "TestTitleNormal";
  const csBoxWidth = windowSize <= 768 ? "BoxWidthSmall" : "BoxWidthNormal";
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Making the app responsive</h1>
      <h2 className={csTestTiele}>{windowSize}</h2>
      <p className={csBoxWidth}>Hello world</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

or use classnames library:

```
import cs from 'classnames';
export default function App() {
  const windowSize = useWindowSize();
  const csTestTiele = cs({
    TestTieleSmall: windowSize <= 768,
    TestTieleNormal: windowSize > 768,
  });
  const csBoxWidth = cs({
    BoxWidthSmall: windowSize <= 768,
    BoxWidthNormal: windowSize > 768,
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Making the app responsive</h1>
      <h2 className={csTestTiele}>{windowSize}</h2>
      <p className={csBoxWidth}>Hello world</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: These examples only show how to dynamically pick a classname. I would have to build 2 classnames for each css class which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: so what are you want?

Comment: I was ideally looking for a solution where I only needed to detect mobile/desktop in 1 place. As it turns out I need to detect it both in react/js and scss it seems. Using styled-components may help but I think it's overkill for the question. I think @aron's comment above is the correct answer: in short, I can't can't pass a JS variable to a .scss file

Comment: I have developed a library [themed-styles](https://github.com/vipcxj/themed-styles). It generate the stylesheet at runtime base on the template. And you can inject js variable to the templat at runtime.  Mybe it's what you want. But I found some other more famous library such as styled-components support similar function, so I haven't maintain it now.

Comment: Appreciate you sharing. I will have a look at your themed-styles but as you suggested I will likely use styled-components.